# Gyradius (Radius of gyration) and CoM

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotation

*Full disclosure, I'm trying to do an exercises but failing to understand it. The course takes for granted some notions I touched many years ago.*

There's a solid object rotating around a joint. Gyradius and CoM are provided as distances from the joint.

Basically the point of the exercise is to calculate the torque around the joint. In the solution it uses the gyradius to calculate rotational inertia, and then calculates rotations around the CoM using this value.

Shouldn't the gyradius (in this case) be calculated as distance from the CoM?

Do I actually need to calculate the gyradius If I'm computing torques around the CoM?

EDIT: I'm so sorry. Probably there's an error in the text solution and he's actually calculating around the joint, and not the CoM.

Comment: In their definition centre of mass depends on distance and the radius of gyration depends on distance $^2$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have edited my question since I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: By "inertia" do you mean "moment of inertia"?

Comment: Sorry, yes exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you have a uniform rod $AB$ of length $L$ which is pivoted at $B$.

[image]

The position of the centre of mass is $\frac L2$ away from the pivot point but the radius of gyration is equal to $\frac{L}{\sqrt 3}$ away from the pivot point ie further that the centre of mass.
The reason for this is that because moment of inertia depends on $\rm mass \times distance^2$ the parts of the rod which are furthest from the pivot have the greatest effect.

If you use the distance to the centre of mass you are in effect converted the rod which has got distributed mass into a point mass.

Comment: _"If you use the distance to the centre of mass you are in effect cinverted the rod which has got distributed mass into a point mass."_
Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @drdud The rod has mass distributed along its length with those masses furthest from the pivot having a bigger effect closer to the pivot. Using the centre of mass means that you have liken the rod to a single point mass thus taking no notice of the fact that masses further from the pivot have a bigger effect.

Comment: thanks. so in that case gyradius wouldn't make sense?

Comment: @drdud Note how the distance you need to use $\frac{L}{\sqrt 3}$ (the radius of gyration) is larger than than the distance of the centre of mass is from the pivot $\frac L2$ reflected the extra weighting of the masses furthest from the pivot.